# How to tidy this data faster?

Tags: r

```
p<-data.frame(x=2001:2019,y=0)

profile2001<-subset(x=profile,subset=(年==2001))

profile2001$女<-as.numeric(profile2001$女)   

profile2001$男<-as.numeric(profile2001$男),

profile2001$女比例<-data.frame(profile2001$女/profile2001$總計女)

profile2001$男比例<-data.frame(profile2001$男/profile2001$總計男)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6rsR.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbUrU.png)

I want to write a code to tidy the data from pic.1 to pic.2. From year 2001 to 2019. Is there faster way to do that? I don't want to do it one by one.

Comment: This should be quite easy using `dplyr`, but please supply a reproducible example using `dput()` so we can help you.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use.Images are not helpful.  Also show expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Learn how to manipulate dataframe with the library `tidyverse`.
Note that tidyverse is made up other key packages like `dplyr`, `tidyr` and `ggplot2` etc. It is a one of the most popular packages to use in R.

Also, in order to get proper help in stackoverflow, you have to learn how to produce a reproducible example. This is especially so for problems that are far more complicated that the one you have raised above.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
random_10 <- round(runif(5)*10)
male <- as.character(random_10 )
female <- as.character(10-random_10)

df <- data.frame(Male = male, Female = female, Total = 10)

df
  Male Female Total
1    3      7    10
2    8      2    10
3    4      6    10
4    9      1    10
5    9      1    10

df %>%
  mutate(Male = as.numeric(Male), Female = as.numeric(Female)) %>%
  mutate(Male_Proportion = Male/Total) %>%
  mutate(Female_Proportion = Female/Total) %>%
  mutate(Male_Percentage = round(Male_Proportion*100,2)) %>%
  mutate(Female_Percentage = round(Female_Proportion*100,2))

  Male Female Total Male_Proportion Female_Proportion Male_Percentage Female_Percentage
1    3      7    10             0.3               0.7              30                70
2    8      2    10             0.8               0.2              80                20
3    4      6    10             0.4               0.6              40                60
4    9      1    10             0.9               0.1              90                10
5    9      1    10             0.9               0.1              90                10
```

To filter using tidyverse, you can use the `filter` function

```
df %>%
  mutate(Male = as.numeric(Male), Female = as.numeric(Female)) %>%
  mutate(Male_Proportion = Male/Total) %>%
  mutate(Female_Proportion = Female/Total) %>%
  mutate(Male_Percentage = round(Male_Proportion*100,2)) %>%
  mutate(Female_Percentage = round(Female_Proportion*100,2)) %>%
  filter(Female >= 6)

  Male Female Total Male_Proportion Female_Proportion Male_Percentage Female_Percentage
1    3      7    10             0.3               0.7              30                70
2    4      6    10             0.4               0.6              40                60
```